# BigQuery - how to determine Data Availability

Tags: streaming, google-bigquery

In regards to: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability

What's the best way to programatically determine if a table's data is available after streaming?

I am getting unexpected results trying to fetch Rows and TotalRows with the following apis: Jobs.Query, Jobs.GetQueryResults, Tables.Get, Tabledata.List

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell whether data is flushed on the table by executing the Tables.Get() API and looking at the streamingBuffer.oldestEntryTime value. This can be considered a high-water mark of data that has been flushed out of the buffer.

Any data before this timestamp should be available for copy, export, and list operations.

Also, I should clarify that data in the table is available for query immediately after streaming. It only is unavailable to table copy, export, and tabledata.list() operations. Yes, this is confusing, but yes, we're also working on addressing the problem.

For tables that haven't been streamed to before or recently, there is a warmup period where new streaming data won't show up.

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jordan. Can you please provide some more information how I would use this field?

You mentioned the data should be available right away for query, however that doesn't seem to be the case all the time for me. I set up a simple test that creates a table, streams 1 row, and then immediately executes a very simple query: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...". Sometimes the test fails because the query returns a value of 0.

Comment: Ah. there is a warmup time of a "few seconds" on new tables. updated my response. This is mentioned in the docs. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability

Comment: So to confirm:  
  
1) How often does the streaming buffer get flushed? The docs mention "Data can take up to 90 minutes to become available", is that the same thing?  
  
2) Does the ~90 minute delay apply to Tabledata.List? what about Tables.Get? As a result, previewing a table that has been streamed to is better done using a query: select * ?  
  
3) Is there something I can wait on until the warm up of a "few seconds" is finished?  
  
4) Is streamingBuffer a transient object, or will it persist forever after the first streamed batch. I read the docs but would like to confirm.

Comment: 1) Up to 90 minutes, but usually within a few minutes. 2)  Yes / Yes / Yes 3) poll on streamingBuffer being on the table. 4) It will go away 24 hours or so after streaming completes.

Comment: Another question just came up. Does the warm up period for new tables (time before a table can be queried) apply only to streamed tables, or any tables? e.g. tables loaded from cloud storage, tables that are query results...

Comment: The warm-up period applies only to streaming. Other methods of writing to tables are ACID; data is immediately and atomically available.